# Render only part of 3D model

Tags: three.js

I have a big 3D model of a house and I would like to load only a small part of it instead of the whole model, e.g. only a 5*5*5 cube at specific position.

Is there a way to modify or truncate a 3D model in Three js? Is there another way to achive something like this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying you want to be able to define a box, and only render the vertices/faces of the model within that box? If so, you're probably looking for clipping planes. Take a look at [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clip#webgl_clipping_intersection), which can be made to show only 1/8th of the sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the whole model and use [BufferGeometry.drawRange](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/BufferGeometry.drawRange) to determine what part of the geometry should be rendered.

Simple example with a box geometry: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/3435/

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
geometry.drawRange.count = 18; // draw half of the geometry
```

If you don't want to load the entire model, i suggest you split it into subparts with a 3D modeling tool like Blender. You can then load and manage the parts separately.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Is it also possible to render only a small square of a model at a specific position?

Comment: Basically yes. You can specify the exact range via `drawRange.start` and `drawRange.count`. Use the method `.setDrawRange()` for this task.